# How do I fit an existing logo into a square?

Tags: logo

How can I make this logo I created fit into a square? Aesthetically, I just can't get it to look right. I had originally designed it to be used as a banner, but now the organization wants to use it as their Facebook profile picture. Any ideas?
[image: WWLW Logo]

Edit: This is what I have tried, if anyone has any feedback that would be appreciated. No, I am not trying to get "free work" as someone had mentioned, I will do everything myself... I'm just having issues getting things to look good.  Here are two that I liked.  I like the faded coloring of the first one because it doesn't hurt the eyes (a hard task with these colors) and the second is just very bland so I don't know how to feel about it at all. 
[image: Picture1] 
[image: Picture2]

Comment: Why you cant get it to look right? How you convert a logo to square? Ideas about what?

Comment: I want to move things around so it would fill up an entire square, but all my ideas looked bad.

Comment: What about a polka pattern with the colors of the rainbow as the background, that would fill a square. It would be colorful as the community itself.

Comment: Could you please show us what hou have tried? It's always good to show a little effort, and it increases your chances of getting a solid answer. Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be "idea gathering" (off-topic) and not a "critique" to me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using JUST the iconography as a more emblematic approach for the profile photo?

You're not asking a technical question, you're asking a creative one. There's a thousand options here. This is where you, as the designer, have a chance to show what you can make from a less-than-ideal situation. Good way to cut teeth!

Open up several .Ai artboards and rearrange away until you find something that meets the need!